# I want to move my closed question... And already flagged it, but no action

Tags: support

I want to move my closed question, on "Ape to Human Diagram" and "Dehumanization", to the Psychology Stack.

But I've already flagged it, but no action...

Do I flag it again, or delete and remake, as someone suggested?

But then I'll lose my points?

Also, how do I link to questions, from the Mobile App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that I made some mistake in handling the flag on the question; I don't think I noticed the comment about moving it to psychology, and thought the question was flagged for some other reason. I've contacted the psychology mods, asking if they'd be interested in taking the question, and I'll update you once I get a reply.

Update: The question has now been migrated to Psychology and Neuroscience.